# using qt header files in android ndk

Tags: c++, qt, android-ndk, header-files

I want to use a cpp library that is using QT in android studio project. the problem is that android studio cannot make project because Qt header files are not present in ndk toolchain. how we can solve this problem?

Comment: By instructing CMake to look for the Qt library and correctly linking it to your code.

Comment: One way is to build your library and include it in your AS project. Another way is to use qt creator (recommended). Otherwise you should use cmake and YASM to build your project (I havn’t had any experience with this method) does your cpp library has a cmakelist with it?

Comment: @Iman unfortunately it does not have a cmakelist

Comment: I suggest to write a cmakelist for it and compile the library and then include the binary into your AS project. Provided that you don’t need to tweak the library code, it is by far the most easiest approach in your situation (personal opinion).

Comment: I agree with @Iman. Example how to use prebuilt libraries (in your case it is Qt libraries) can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64398479/how-to-link-a-to-so-and-create-new-so-for-android/64433504#64433504