# How to link .a to .so and create new .so for android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I have an existing android project where a .so (say existing.so) is packaged and loaded in some .aar (say existing.aar). That existing.so file exposed a symbol(funcion) which my .a (my.a) static library will use. How to include my.a file in that particular project so that it get links to existing.so ? Should a new .so made linking my.a and existing.so ? I can add cmake or ndk dependency in that existing project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the native prebuilt libraries are provided via the .aar prefab, here's a [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/native-dependencies?buildsystem=cmake&agpversion=4.1) from Android Developers of how to do it, if not, you need to do it like you would for a normal CMake project:

1. Lay your prebuilt libraries in such order:

```
libs/${ANDROID_PLATFORM}/${ANDROID_ABI}/existing
libs/${ANDROID_PLATFORM}/${ANDROID_ABI}/my
```

e.g.:

```
libs/android-28/x86_64/existing/lib/existing.so
libs/android-28/x86_64/existing/include/existing.h
libs/android-28/x86_64/my/lib/my.a
libs/android-28/x86_64/my/include/my.h
```

2. Add paths to APPEND CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH in your project .so:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH libs/${ANDROID_PLATFORM}/${ANDROID_ABI}/existing)
list(APPEND CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH libs/${ANDROID_PLATFORM}/${ANDROID_ABI}/my)
```

3. Now you can use them from your project .so:

```
find_library(existing_lib existing)
find_library(my_lib my)

add_library(project SHARED <source_files>)
target_link_libraries(project existing_lib my_lib)
```

Comment: Do I need to copy existing.so in libs folder ? Actually it is already packed as third party library in some .aar. How to add dependency for that ?

Comment: I guess yes, if you want to use it outside the .aar from CMake file. Also you need to provide corresponding header files because, as I know, .aar doesn't do it.

Comment: And I like your answer 

Comment: Is there a way I can add dependency of .so which is already inside .aar/.apk to cmake ?

Comment: Digging deeper, I found that it is possible to use native libraries directly from the .aar package by using the Prefab feature: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/native-dependencies?buildsystem=cmake Does your .aar contain Prefab stuff?

Comment: Unfortunately the aar does not contain prefab enabled. It is generated by some other team.

Comment: I understood. So I've added a prefab case to my answer and it looks like it covers all cases now.