# How to prevent my JNI folder from rebuilding?

Tags: android, c++, c, flutter, android-ndk

Anytime I clear build folder in flutter (either with `flutter clean` or manually), my jni folder rebuilds (~40 mins). Is that possible to compile library to some binary, and use it from android without breaking any interfaces and functionality?

P.S. My library consists of many folders and contains .mk, .c, .cpp, .h files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is that possible to compile library to some binary, and use it from android without breaking any interfaces and functionality?

Of course yes. Build you libraries like shared `.so` or static `.a` and use them like prebuilts. Here the example how to use native prebuilt libraries: [How to link .a to .so and create new .so for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64398479/how-to-link-a-to-so-and-create-new-so-for-android/64433504#64433504)

Moreover, you can also put them together with the used SDK, NDK, AS, and other thirdparties in Docker image and work with your project from Docker.