# Link Static Library in Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk

Can anyone solve this problem?? It is a simple source when I see but doesn't run linking on android NDK.

I'm done on CLion for library and make an *.a file using a CMake.

[image: Directory Structure]

And, Contents of CMakeList.txt is.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project("Library")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_library(_test STATIC library.cpp)
target_include_directories(_test PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
```

On library.cpp... just print "Hello World" in "void hello();"

After, I made it "lib_test.a" and then copied to Android Project with header file

[image: Android Project Directory]

Then, Setup CMakeList.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(core-launcher)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(CORE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/core)
set(INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

#include_directories(${CORE_DIR})

#######################################
###       CORE STATIC LIBRARY       ###
#######################################

add_library(lib-test STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(lib-test PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CORE_DIR}/lib_test.a)


#######################################

add_library(core-launcher SHARED
    bridge.cpp
)

find_library(
    log-lib
    log
)

target_include_directories(core-launcher PUBLIC ${INCLUDE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(
    core-launcher
    lib-test

    ${log-lib}
)
```

[image: Bridge Image]

But Console said, That "hello();" function is undefined reference..

Do I have to add some options on library's CMakeList or somewhere?

Comment: You can not just copy side libraries from elsewhere into android project and expect them to work. They need to be compiled using compiler from NDK with appropriate targeting.

Comment: Here the example how to use prebuilt libraries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64398479/how-to-link-a-to-so-and-create-new-so-for-android/64433504#64433504