# JNI missing symbol in library built on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, java-native-interface

My JNI project links against 3 shared libraries: libogg, libvorbis and libtheora.
On Windows everything works fine, and on Linux there are no errors when building my shared library. However, I'm getting a missing symbol: `oggpack_readinit`.

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(theoraplayer)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

include_directories(include)
include_directories(jnihelpers)
link_directories(lib)

if(ANDROID)
    set(CMAKE_C_CFLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -D__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++")
else()
    find_package(JNI REQUIRED)
endif(ANDROID)

include_directories(${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS})

if (JNI_FOUND)
    message (STATUS "JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS=${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    message (STATUS "JNI_LIBRARIES=${JNI_LIBRARIES}")
else()
    message(STATUS "JNI Not found")
endif()

file(GLOB libJniHelpers_SOURCES jnihelpers/*.cpp)
file(GLOB libJniHelpers_HEADERS jnihelpers/*.h)

add_library(theoraplayer SHARED TheoraPlayer.h TheoraPlayer.cpp theoraplay/theoraplay.c ${libJniHelpers_SOURCES} ${libJniHelpers_HEADERS} NativeLogger.h NativeLogger.cpp VideoFrame.h VideoFrame.cpp TheoraDecoder.h TheoraDecoder.cpp MediaInfo.h MediaInfo.cpp AudioPacket.h AudioPacket.cpp)

set_target_properties(theoraplayer PROPERTIES BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE)
set_target_properties(theoraplayer PROPERTIES INSTALL_RPATH "./")
target_link_libraries(theoraplayer ogg vorbis theora)

if(${UNIX})
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fPIC -O2 -Wl,--no-as-needed")
elseif(${WINDOWS})
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "/MP /EHsc /O2 /GL")
endif(${UNIX})
```

When I run `ldd` on the built library, none of the 3 libraries show up:

```
ldd libtheoraplayer.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffadd8c000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fdfc9ed0000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fdfc9d88000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fdfc9d68000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fdfc9b98000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fdfca138000)
```

Comment: Here the example how to use native prebuilt libraries for Android NDK project, maybe it will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64433504/5130269

Comment: So I should use for example libogg.so instead of libogg.a?

Comment: No, you just need to point to cmake where your prebuilts are placed by setting ```CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH``` and use ```find_library()``` to find them.

Comment: Now I can see them being linked when I run ldd, but there are still unresolved symbols, now from libtheora

Comment: What kind of symbols? Are those libraries built by using Android NDK toolchain (as I understand you are trying to apply it for Android)?

Comment: No, I'm not trying to build for Android at the moment, just 64-bit Linux. They are built from  the sources of these libraries (libogg, libtheora, libvorbis) by running `./configure` and `make`